# Query to roll over weekends (saturday and Sunday) to next business Day (Monday) if it is same month and

Tags: sql, sql-server

So if we start a month on a weekend the first day becomes the weekend and it should roll over to weekday and similarly Holidays should roll back to previous day.

```
Date        RecognizedBusinessDateKey   RecognizedBusinessDateNumber
7/28/2020   20200728                    19
7/29/2020   20200729                    20
7/30/2020   20200730                    21
7/31/2020   20200731                    22
8/1/2020    20200803                    1
8/2/2020    20200803                    1
8/3/2020    20200803                    1
8/4/2020    20200804                    2

Date        RecognizedBusinessDateKey   RecognizedBusinessDateNumber
5/28/2020   20200528                    19
5/29/2020   20200529                    20
5/30/2020   20200529                    20
5/31/2020   20200529                    20
6/1/2020    20200601                    1
6/2/2020    20200602                    2
6/3/2020    20200603                    3
6/4/2020    20200604                    4

Date        RecognizedBusinessDateKey   RecognizedBusinessDateNumber
6/4/2020    20200604                    4
6/5/2020    20200605                    5
6/6/2020    20200605                    5
6/7/2020    20200608                    6
6/8/2020    20200608                    6
6/9/2020    20200609                    7
```

Data is looking like this in table

[image]

I tried the below query

```
SELECT 
     d.Date
    ,d.DateKey
    ,d.IsBusinessDay
    ,d.MonthKey
    ,ISNULL(MAX(d2.DateKey),d.DateKey) AS RecognizedBusinessDateKey
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY d.MonthKey ORDER BY ISNULL(MAX(d2.DateKey),d.DateKey)) AS RecognizedBusinessDateNumber
FROM dbo.DimDate d
    LEFT JOIN dbo.DimDate d2 
        ON d2.MonthKey <= d.DateKey
WHERE d2.IsBusinessDay = 'Business Day'
  AND d2.DateKey > 0
  AND d2.Date BETWEEN '8/1/2020' AND '8/31/2020'
GROUP BY 
     d.Date
    ,d.DateKey
    ,d.IsBusinessDay
    ,d.MonthKey
```

Comment: Is this data in a table?  What does it look like?  What is your question?

Comment: Data is looking like this in table

Comment: what do you mean by "Query to roll over... " ?

Comment: i need a sort of query that can depict the result in a way shown in first 2 sample data.

Comment: Query i tried -- > SELECT d.Date.DateKey,d.IsBusinessDay,d.MonthKey,ISNULL(MAX(d2.DateKey),d.DateKey) AS BusinessDateKey, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY d.MonthKey ORDER BY ISNULL(MAX(d2.DateKey),d.DateKey)) AS BusinessDateNumber FROM dbo.DimDate d LEFT JOIN dbo.DimDate d2  ON d2.DateKey <= d.DateKey WHERE d2.IsBusinessDay = 'Business Day'  AND d2.DateKey > 0 AND d2.Date BETWEEN '8/1/2020' AND '8/31/2020' GROUP BY  d.Date,d.DateKey,d.IsBusinessDay,d.MonthKey